# django - prevent form submission if submitted form value is X

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am using Django 1.4.6 & python 2.7.

I have a test form that allows the user to enter data from a select list:

```
<select name="language_code" id="id_language_code">
    <option value="en-CA">English (Canada) - English (Canada)‎</option>
    <option value="en-GB" selected="selected">English (UK) - English (UK)‎</option>
    <option value="en">English (US)</option>
    <option value="fr-CA">French (Canada) - français (Canada)‎</option>
    <option value="fr">French (France) - français (France)‎</option>
</select>
```

The form submission is working OK.

However, I need to make a change so that if the user selects the select list option of fr-CA and then submits the form, then I would like to NOT add the record and also redirect the user to a different form - return redirect(settings.MENU_DETAIL_LINK_NAME_DETAILS).

**Essentially, if the boolean field language_code_disabled of LanguageVersion model is true, then the user should not be able to add the language version.**

I am not exactly sure how to do this. I have been going around in circles on this so I have confused myself on how to achieve this.

Here is my models code:

```
class NameDetails(models.Model, FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    language_version = models.ForeignKey('LanguageVersion')
    name_details_prefix_title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=25)
    name_details_first_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=50)
    name_details_middle_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    name_details_last_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=60)
    name_details_suffix_title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=25)

class LanguageVersion(models.Model):
    """Language version selection for a user"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    language_code = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    language_code_disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is my views.py

```
@login_required
def name_details_add(request):
    language_versions = LanguageVersion.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    available_languages = get_available_language_details(language_versions, request.user.userprofile.language_preference)
    name_details_num = request.user.namedetails_set.count()
    preview_labels = get_name_details_labels(available_languages)
    if name_details_num >= settings.MAX_NAME_DETAILS:
        return redirect(settings.MENU_DETAIL_LINK_NAME_DETAILS)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = NameDetailsForm(
            available_languages=available_languages,
            language_preference=request.user.userprofile.language_preference,)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameDetailsForm(
            available_languages=available_languages,
            language_preference=request.user.userprofile.language_preference,
            data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and name_details_num < settings.MAX_NAME_DETAILS:
            name_detail = NameDetails(user=request.user)
            name_detail.fill(form.cleaned_data)
            name_detail.save()
            messages.success(request, _('successfully added.'))
            return redirect(settings.MENU_DETAIL_LINK_NAME_DETAILS)
```

I am hoping that somone can help me out on this issue.

I need to find out how to call a list of all language codes from the LanguageVersions model of the user where the language_code_disabled is True.

**Do I write a function that will loop through the language versions or can I write a simple call function to return a list of disabled language codes, such as en, fr, fr-CA, de ?**

```
disabled_language_versions = LanguageVersion.objects.filter(user=request.user, language_code_disabled=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a field validation for the LanguageVersion fk on the form, and access that information in the view:

```
class NameDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def clean_language_version(self):
        lang = self.cleaned_data.get('language_version')
        if LanguageVersion.objects.filter(language_code=lang, language_code_disabled=True).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Language code disabled")
        return lang
```

then in the view:

```
if form.is_valid() ... :
    ...
elif form['language_version'].errors:
    return redirect(settings.MENU_DETAIL_LINK_NAME_DETAILS)
```

Comment: DRC, appreciate the response. Cannot get the code to work. Form simply submits.

Comment: @user1261774 you can inject a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the clean_language_version function and see why it passes that if.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this:

```
if request.POST['language_code'] == 'fr-CA':
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/some/other/page/')
```

Comment: xyres, thanks. this code does works. but how do call the language_code_disabled from the LanguageVersion model as ther will be many disabled language codes?